# Pandas groupby to get percent of total rows by specific label

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Working with Pandas, I would like to calculate the percentage of rows that have a positive value in a specific column for a distinct breakdown.

---

## Input

An example likely illustrates this easiest so assume I have a table named `table` shown below:

```
| ID | Name    | Sex | Number |
|----|---------|-----|--------|
| 1  | Jim     | M   | -1     |
| 2  | Carly   | F   | 1      |
| 3  | Joe     | M   | 0      |
| 4  | Barbara | F   | -1     |
| 5  | Susan   | F   | -2     |
| 6  | Phyllis | F   | 2      |
| 7  | John    | M   | 3      |
```

I want to, **in the most efficient way possible**, calculate the number of rows where the `Number` column is greater than 0, for each sex (M or F).

---

## Output

I expect a DataFrame output like the following:

```
| Sex | Percent|
|-----|--------|
| M   | 0.33   |
| F   | 0.5    |
```

These percentages, again, are the number of rows where `df['Sex']=` (`M` or `F`) **AND** `df['Number'] > 0`

---

---

## Tried

In this case, it seems easiest to subset the data and calculate it separately, which I have tried with the following:

```
male_df = df.loc[df['Sex']=='M']]
female_df = df.loc[df['Sex']=='F']]
d = {'M': None, 'F': None}
for sex_df, label in [(male_df, 'M'), (female_df, 'F')]:
    d[label] = len(d.loc[d['Number'] > 0])/len(d)
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, columns=['Sex','Percent'])
```

## HOWEVER

My **real** data is actually subsetted by multiple columns, so doing individual `.loc()` calls for each subset is not practical. I was thinking there would be a way to implement this with pandas' `.groupby()` method, however do not know where to start.

Comment: How come for `F` is it 0.5? There is only one value >0

Comment: @harvpan OOps, I updated the table but forgot to update it in my question... I will update now

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html  just to understand  that you probably wanna do something like df.groupby(['Number', 'Sex'])

Comment: @Taku_ I don't want to group on number, as this creates individual groups for each distinct number. I only want groups for `Sex` in this example. The aggregation of the groupby is going to be performed on the Number column I would assume

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most efficient is to take the mean of a Boolean Series within group (`GroupBy.mean` will use cython). Since the Series we create shares the same index of the DataFrame, you can group in this way:

```
df['Number'].gt(0).groupby(df['Sex']).mean()
#Sex
#F    0.500000
#M    0.333333
#Name: Number, dtype: float64
```

Comment: How would this extend if we were grouping on 2 different fields, such as 'Sex' and 'Age Group' (imagining this field existed)

Comment: One way is to assign the column to the DataFrame `df.assign(my_col = df.Number.gt(0)).groupby(['Sex', 'Age Group']).my_col.mean()`. But I think that might unnecessarily copy the rest of the DataFrame.  So instead you could do the above, but provide a list of Series `df['Number'].gt(0).groupby([df['Sex'], df['Age Group']]).mean()`

Comment: This worked perfectly. I never though to just create a boolean from my conditionals. Thanks! :)